# Use numpy.argwhere to obtain the matching values in an np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to use `np.argwhere()` to obtain the values in an `np.array`.

For example:

```
z = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

zi = np.argwhere(z % 3 == 0)

[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [2 0]]
```

I want this array: `[0, 3, 6]` and did this:

`t = [z[tuple(i)] for i in zi] # -> [0, 3, 6]`

I assume there is an easier way.

Comment: Try : `z[tuple(zi.T)]`.

Comment: `zi=np.where(....)` can be used directly `t=z[zi]`.  It's a tuple of indexing arrays.  `argwhere` is its transpose.  Compare their outputs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not simply use masking here:

```
z[z % 3 == 0]
```

For your sample matrix, this will generate:

```
>>> z[z % 3 == 0]
array([0, 3, 6])
```

If you pass a matrix with the same dimensions with booleans as indices, you get an array with the elements of that matrix where the boolean matrix is `True`.

This will furthermore work more efficient, since you do the filtering at the numpy level (whereas list comprehension works at the Python interpreter level).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still getting used to the ways in which numpy arrays can be indexed so this wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: numpy operations are faster so for large datasets np is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Source for `argwhere`

```
def argwhere(a):
    """
    Find the indices of array elements that are non-zero, grouped by element.
    ...
    """
    return transpose(nonzero(a))
```

`np.where` is the same as `np.nonzero`.

```
In [902]: z=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [903]: z%3==0
Out[903]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [904]: np.nonzero(z%3==0)
Out[904]: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
In [905]: np.transpose(np.nonzero(z%3==0))
Out[905]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [906]: z[[0,1,2], [0,0,0]]
Out[906]: array([0, 3, 6])
```

`z[np.nonzero(z%3==0)]` is equivalent to using `I,J` as indexing arrays:

```
In [907]: I,J =np.nonzero(z%3==0)
In [908]: I
Out[908]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [909]: J
Out[909]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [910]: z[I,J]
Out[910]: array([0, 3, 6])
```