# Length of passed values is 1, index implies 10

Tags: pandas

**Why and what is this error about??? It shows Length of passed
values is 1, index implies 10. I tried many times to run the
code and I come across the same**

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 50, 10))
result = np.argwhere(ser % 3==0)
print(result)
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the values of `np.random.randint(1, 50, 10)`, you will find that it generates 10 random integers. The command is randint(low, high, size)

Comment: yes it is generating 10 random integers and i want to pull multiples of 3 from that series without looping

Comment: @ADITYAOZA Please post your expected output.

Comment: The expected output will the list of position of numbers which are multiples of 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argwhere()` operates on a numpy array not a panda series.  See below

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 50, 12)
a = pd.Series(a)
print(a)
np.argwhere(a.values%3==0)
```

### output

```
0     28
1     46
2      4
3     40
4     19
5     26
6      6
7     24
8     26
9     30
10    33
11    27
dtype: int64
[250]:
array([[ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 9],
       [10],
       [11]])
```

Comment: That actually was a very helpful comment, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation for [numpy.random.randint](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) You will see that the parameters are (low, high, size).

In your case, you are sending (1, 50, 10). So 10 random numbers will be generated between 1 and 50.

If you want multiples of 3, then you need to do this `ser[ser % 3==0]` not use [np.anywhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

See similar issue raised earlier and answered on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255167/use-numpy-argwhere-to-obtain-the-matching-values-in-an-np-array)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 50, 10))
print (ser)
result = ser[ser % 3==0]
print(result)
```

Output of this will be:

Original Series.

```
0    17
1    34
2    29
3    15
4    24
5    20
6    21
7    48
8     6
9    42
dtype: int64
```

Multiples of 3 will be:

```
3    15
4    24
6    21
7    48
8     6
9    42
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html):

```
In [1374]: ser
Out[1374]: 
0    44
1     5
2    35
3    10
4    16
5    20
6    25
7     9
8    44
9    16
dtype: int64

In [1372]: l = ser[ser % 3 == 0].index.tolist()

In [1373]: l
Out[1373]: [7]
```

where `l` will be a `list` of `indexes` of elements which are a multiple of `3`.